# Regex to match blocks inside blocks

Tags: php, regex

I have the follow string:

```
{% if a == 3 %}
    Yes
{% else %}
    {% if b == 2 %}
        Maybe
    {% else %}
        {% if c == 1 %}
            Hm... Not
        {% else %}
            No way!
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% if d == 0 %}
    Ok
{% endif %}
```

If I use this regexp 
`/\{%\s*if\s*(.*?)\s*%\}(.*)(\{%\s*else\s*%\}(.*))?\{%\s*endif\s*%\}/ism`
(in preg_match_all function on PHP), my return is all code above. But when I use 
`/\{%\s*if\s*(.*?)\s*%\}(.*?)(\{%\s*else\s*%\}(.*?))?\{%\s*endif\s*%\}/ism`
(just out of greedy mode), my return ends at `{% endif %}` of `{% if c == 1 %}` if (the first endif found).

I want to get the following return:

1.

```
{% if a == 3 %}
    Yes
{% else %}
    {% if b == 2 %}
        Maybe
    {% else %}
        {% if c == 1 %}
            Hm... Not
        {% else %}
            No way!
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

2.

```
{% if d == 0 %}
    Ok
{% endif %}
```

How should be my regex to archive this return?

PS. I know, if I put some name on ifs and use this name on endif, it could be easily resolved using backreference... But I DO NOT want a palliative answer

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regular expressions are not well suited for processing recursive structures like this. Although PHP has extensions which support recursive regular expressions, I'd recommend writing a proper parser instead.

Comment: As p.s.w.g points out, PHP isn't good at parsing long strings like this and it leads to some quite funky regex. If possible, think about changing the input string to something more manageable like json, xml etc, then you can use native PHP functions for parsing it easily

Comment: This could be done with simple recursion. The only problem is that all the language intrinsic need to be defined. So, its not the recursion, its the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this recursive pattern:

```
$pattern = '~{% if [^%]+%}(?>[^{]+|(?R))*(?>{% else %}(?>[^{]+|(?R))*)?{% endif %}~';
```

[online demo](http://regex101.com/r/oY8eH4/1)

pattern details:

```
~
{% if [^%]+%}
(?>                  # this atomic group describes the content
                     # between if/else/endif markups:
    [^{]+            #  - all that is not an opening curly bracket
  |                  # OR
    (?R)             #  - recursion (repeat the whole pattern)
)*                   # repeat the group zero or more times
(?>
    {% else %}       # The "else" part works exactly in the same way,
    (?>[^{]+|(?R))*
)?                   # but is optional
{% endif %}
~
```

Comment: _One day a genius person will implement whole PHP interpreter with a single regex .._

Answer (score 0):

I extended this example to solve my own problem, specially to have some random {% ... %} in it: [regex101 online demo](http://regex101.com/r/rK9fV4/1)